# TypeError: message.mentions.channels is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I am currently working on an announce command. I only have problem, when I run the command I get an error.

Code:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {


    let channel = message.mentions.channels();
    let announcement = args.slice(1).join(" ");

    channel.send(announcement);


}

module.exports.help = {
    name: "ann"
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: message.mentions.channels is not a function
```

I hope someone can help me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

`channels()` is not a thing.

And you also did not specify which channel from the mentions you want as there could be multiple at the same time, that's why you need to use `first()` to choose the first mentioned channel.

```js
let channel = message.mentions.channels.first();
```

Comment: Now I only get this error:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined`

@Syntle

Comment: Are you mentioning a channel?

Comment: i do `!ann @here test`

Comment: that's not mentioning a channel, if let's say your channel is called `rules` you need to mention it by using `#` so it'd be `#rules`

Comment: Now I do this: `!ann #announcements test` and I get the same error

Comment: Are you using dicord.js v12 or v11?

Comment: `"discord.js": "^12.2.0",`

Comment: @Syntle I think you've gotten a little mixed up - as of the latest version, the `MessageMentions` object does not contain any caches, only Collections. `message.mentions.channels` should be a `Collection<Snowflake, GuildChannel>`. Getting the first mentioned channel should be `message.mentions.channels.first()`.

Comment: What do I have to adjust now? @Klaycon